# Is it possible to update the log level of a zap logger at runtime?

Tags: go, logging, go-zap

I created a logger with `kubebuilder`, it is based on zap logger:

```
import (
    "flag"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "go.uber.org/zap/zapcore"
    uzap "go.uber.org/zap"
    // Import all Kubernetes client auth plugins (e.g. Azure, GCP, OIDC, etc.)
    // to ensure that exec-entrypoint and run can make use of them.
    _ "k8s.io/client-go/plugin/pkg/client/auth"

    "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/runtime"
    utilruntime "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/runtime"
    clientgoscheme "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes/scheme"
    ctrl "sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime"
    "sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/healthz"
    "sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/log/zap"

)

var (
    scheme   = runtime.NewScheme()
    setupLog = ctrl.Log.WithName("setup")
)

var zapOpts []uzap.Option
    zapOpts = append(zapOpts, uzap.AddCaller())
    zapOpts = append(zapOpts, uzap.AddCallerSkip(1))
    zapOpts = append(zapOpts, uzap.AddStacktrace(uzap.DebugLevel))

    opts := zap.Options{
        Development:     developmentFlag,
        StacktraceLevel: stacktraceLevel,
        Level:           level,
        Encoder:         encoder,
        ZapOpts:  zapOpts,
    }

    opts.BindFlags(flag.CommandLine)
    flag.Parse()

    ctrl.SetLogger(zap.New(zap.UseFlagOptions(&opts)))
```

Now I want to change the log level to `zapcore.InfoLevel` at run time. I didn't find any `SetLogLevel` or similar API.

Do I need to create new opts and then set the new level?

Also I need to set the logger with `sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/log/zap` library. The interface of the logger is from `go-logr` and it implements [`logr.Logger`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-logr/logr#Logger) interface. If I tried to change it to `zapcore.NewCore` than I can't set the logger with `ctrl.SetLogger` anymore.

I want to keep the options to update all the options of `zap.Options`    and also to change the log level, and still to use the zap from `sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/log/zap`.

Is it possible to do it with
`sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/log/zap`
and `sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Better answer**: as [suggested by @Oliver Dain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71515499), use `zap.AtomicLevel`. See their answer for details.

Another option is to create a core with a custom `LevelEnabler` function. You can use [`zap.LevelEnablerFunc`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.uber.org/zap#LevelEnablerFunc) to convert a closure to a [`zapcore.LevelEnabler`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.uber.org/zap/zapcore#LevelEnabler).

The relevant docs:

> LevelEnabler decides whether a given logging level is enabled when logging a message.

> LevelEnablerFunc is a convenient way to implement zapcore.LevelEnabler with an anonymous function.

That function may then return `true` or `false` based on some other variable that changes at runtime:

```
    // will be actually initialized and changed at run time 
    // based on your business logic
    var infoEnabled bool 

    errorUnlessEnabled := zap.LevelEnablerFunc(func(level zapcore.Level) bool {
        // true: log message at this level
        // false: skip message at this level
        return level >= zapcore.ErrorLevel || infoEnabled
    })

    core := zapcore.NewCore(
        zapcore.NewJSONEncoder(zap.NewProductionEncoderConfig()),
        os.Stdout,
        errorUnlessEnabled,
    )
    logger := zap.New(core)

    logger.Info("foo") // not logged
    
    infoEnabled = true

    logger.Info("foo again") // logged
```

PS: this code is contrived. Your program will have to implement initialization, value change at run-time and proper synchronization (if needed) over the `infoEnabled` variable.

You can run this example in the playground: https://play.golang.org/p/oT3nvnP1Bwc

Comment: thanks for the help , I am little bit confused how I can pass the zap.Options{
  Development:     developmentFlag,
  StacktraceLevel: stacktraceLevel,
  Level:           level,
  Encoder:         logfmtEncoder,
  ZapOpts:  zapOpts,
 } ,

Comment: @user1365697 `zap` in your case is `sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/log/zap`, isn't it? Then you can set `errorUnlessEnabled` into `zap.Options.Level` field. The type is the same as in my example, `zapcore.LevelEnabler`

Comment: @ blackgreen - The issue that I need to use the library  "sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/log/zap" and ctrl "sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime" when I set the logger and not direct with "go.uber.org/zap"

Comment: @user1365697 to use `ctrl.SetLogger` with a custom zap logger, it seems you can use the `github.com/go-logr/zapr` package. `zapr.NewLogger` or [`zapr.NewLoggerWithOptions`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-logr/zapr#NewLoggerWithOptions). Please let me know if this may work, and I'll update the answer

Answer (score 9):

Yes [it is possible](https://pkg.go.dev/go.uber.org/zap#example-AtomicLevel) using `AtomicLevel`. From the docs:

```golang
atom := zap.NewAtomicLevel()

// To keep the example deterministic, disable timestamps in the output.
encoderCfg := zap.NewProductionEncoderConfig()
encoderCfg.TimeKey = ""

logger := zap.New(zapcore.NewCore(
    zapcore.NewJSONEncoder(encoderCfg),
    zapcore.Lock(os.Stdout),
    atom,
))
defer logger.Sync()

logger.Info("info logging enabled")
atom.SetLevel(zap.ErrorLevel)
logger.Info("info logging disabled")
```

Comment: Do I have to keep variable atom as global to be able to change log level somewhere else in other packages ? I could not find a way to retrieve the created atom variable and I know it is possible via rest api which ı do not want to use

Comment: You have to keep it *somewhere* but that need not be global. You have some code somewhere that needs to be able to access the level so that code needs access to `atom` but you could pass it to that code, or pass it to a thing that code has access to, etc.

Comment: It would be nice to get it form zap. Thanks