# Is it possible to update the log level of a zap logger at runtime with MultiWriterSyncer?

Tags: go, logging, go-zap

A follow-up to the question [Is it possible to update the log level of a zap logger at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69738222/6740589)

```golang
import (
    "sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/log/zap"
    "go.uber.org/zap/zapcore"
    lumberjack "gopkg.in/natefinch/lumberjack.v2"
)

func main() {
    ...
    opts := zap.Options{}
    lbjConfig := &lumberjack.Logger{}
    consoleDebugging := zapcore.Lock(os.Stderr)
    multiWriteSyncer := zapcore.NewMultiWriteSyncer(zapcore.AddSync(lbjConfig), consoleDebugging)
    opts.DestWriter = multiWriteSyncer

    ctrl.SetLogger(zap.New(zap.UseFlagOptions(&opts)))
    ...
}
```